# Is it possible to open a webpage with headers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, header, authorization, window.open

Is it possible to open a webpage with headers?

I need to be able to pass a JWT within the headers, and not the query parameters.

The query parameters can be saved into logs, and that's a security risk.

I know that it's not possible to open a webpage with headers using window.open(), but is it possible with Vanilla Javascript?

If so, then how?

I'm using React to build this Proof of Concept.

Comment: There is an open issue for adding support for headers to the window.open function in the HTML standard. Please voice your opinions and needs on there. [https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7810](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7810)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to send headers with `window.open()` and not possible to open new page with headers, but with javascript inside one page it is possible:

Example with fetch:

```
 fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
}
```

Example with XMLHttpRequest:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", '/server', true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
        // Request finished. Do processing here.
    }
}
xhr.send("foo=bar&lorem=ipsum");
```